# Azure AD B2C authresp?code loop until timeout

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am having a real struggle with Azure B2C. I used to have multiple Sign in/Sign up policies which I now reduced to only one SignInOrSignUp type thinking that perhaps that was causing an issue.

However, even with a single policy, the issue is still here.

My policy has 4 social media logins available as well as local account sign in/sign up.

It successfully works 50% of the time. Very often what I find happening is that I get redirected to microsoftonline, select a social media account e.g. facebook, and then the website goes into a loop that results in "Timeout".

https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/viewingbookerad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp?code=[CODE]

Looking at that browser address, it looks like the [CODE] is being refreshed every 2-3 seconds. [CODE] is being regenerated every 2-3 sec and then after good 5 minutes, I end up with "Timeout".

I added 
    name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="true"
header but still no effect.

Here is my startup class

```cs
public partial class Startup {
  // App config settings
  private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
  private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
  private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
  private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
  public static string SignInSignUpPolicy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignInSignUpPolicy"];

  public void Configuration (IAppBuilder app) {
    ConfigureAuth (app);
  }

  public void ConfigureAuth (IAppBuilder app) {
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication (new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
      // if this is "always" we get a infinite loop when authentication on HTTP (HTTPS is fine)
      CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
    });

    // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication (CreateOptionsFromPolicy (SignInSignUpPolicy));
  }

  // Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
  private Task AuthenticationFailed (AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) {
    var logger = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<vb.com.service.Interfaces.ILogger> ();

    notification.HandleResponse ();
    if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied") {
      logger.Fatal ("B2C Error in AuthenticationFailed : access_denied", true);
      notification.Response.Redirect ("/");
    } else if (notification.Exception.Message == "server_error") {
      logger.Fatal ("B2C Error in AuthenticationFailed : server_error", true);
      notification.Response.Redirect ("/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
    } else {
      logger.Fatal ("B2C Error in AuthenticationFailed : " + notification.Exception.Message, true);
      notification.Response.Redirect ("/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
    }

    return Task.FromResult (0);
  }

  private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy (string policy) {
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
      // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
      // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
      MetadataAddress = String.Format (aadInstance, tenant, policy),
        AuthenticationType = policy,

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
          AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
          },
          Scope = "openid",
          ResponseType = "id_token",

          // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
          TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
          NameClaimType = "name",
          SaveSigninToken = true //important to save the token in boostrapcontext
          }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use your browser's developer tools (F12) to trace the network calls and put a screenshot of that in your question. Often times the loop is caused by the application that doesn't handle B2C's response correctly and simply redirects back to B2C.

Comment: Hi @Saca I added a screen capture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xpdh_LNVuBs 

You can see that the code is being regenerated multiple times. It takes about 2-3 minutes before I get Timeout error message back on my website.

This even happens in incognito mode too. This particular test is with all the cookies, browsing history etc. cleared.

Comment: @Saca I think I've just fixed this issue... Here is what's happened: In my login method, I had the following code:

HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Url.Action("CompleteSignInSignUp", "Account") }, Startup.SignInSignUpPolicy);

However CompleteSignInSignUp was in [Authorized] controller. Looks like adding [AllowAnonymous] fixed the issue? Could this be a reason why it sometimes got stuck when returning to my website?

Thanks.